# Jboss java API to get running apps in server with their status

Tags: java, api, jboss

I am using JBOSS AS7 and I want to get deployed/running applications in the server with their status deployed/failed using Java or JBOSS API.

Please let me know if any one can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Bharat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all my research i have found the answer. Here is the API https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin for getting running apps in server.

After creating the client below code snippet will get the results.

```
import static org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.ClientConstants.CHILD_TYPE;
import static org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.ClientConstants.DEPLOYMENT;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.Operations;

ModelNode op = Operations.createOperation("read-children-names");
op.get(CHILD_TYPE).set(DEPLOYMENT);
final ModelNode listDeploymentsResult = client.execute(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some trick to get your job done. Following are the few options:

1. Check `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` folder for files with the name app.war.deployed or app.war.failed.
2. In the `server.log` file in `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log` folder, check for string `Deployed "app.war"`. If the string is there, then your application is deployed else not.

Comment: Thanks akhil, but I am using clustering domain mode deployment and using JBOSS management API URL https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API#ThenativemanagementAPI-requestformat  to deploy, but not able to get the list of apps already running in server.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+API+reference)

```
static ModelControllerClient createClient(final InetAddress host, final int port,
                  final String username, final char[] password, final String securityRealmName) {

    final CallbackHandler callbackHandler = new CallbackHandler() {

        public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
            for (Callback current : callbacks) {
                if (current instanceof NameCallback) {
                    NameCallback ncb = (NameCallback) current;
                    ncb.setName(username);
                } else if (current instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                    PasswordCallback pcb = (PasswordCallback) current;
                    pcb.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
                } else if (current instanceof RealmCallback) {
                    RealmCallback rcb = (RealmCallback) current;
                    rcb.setText(rcb.getDefaultText());
                } else {
                    throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(current);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(host, port, callbackHandler);
}
```

Comment: Hi,can you please let me know the API to get the running apps in server using ModelControllerClient..

Comment: Yes,You can test from POJO class